# Chat-room starred data >9 then it won't scroll up-down

Tags: support, chat

In a chat room I recently got one issue as per the below image;

1. When I got inside then it's showing  `starred only show top 1`. I clicked then I got the below view:

   [image]
2. and I clicked again on  `starred show 9 more`. I clicked then I got the below view all the 9 starred, but my problem is it won't scroll any more in up or down direction. I am unable to see below all starred.

[image]

How does it work? If I supposed to see all the 9 starred at the same place?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see this "*starred show 9 more" option at all.

Comment: @DavidArenburg And i see but is not worked expected.

Comment: It shows up when the screen height is too small to accommodate 10 messages. It's pretty useless, because the list just closes again after a few seconds.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113595/starred-messages-in-chat-room

Comment: @MD Nice observation.